# Pass XML data as a parameter in string SQL Query c# from List

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ado.net

I have to pass data in some structured format which is at the code side in a List of an anonymous type to the SQL which is then converted into a Temp table and therefore used in further joins. Currently, I am looping through the data and creating a string using StringBuilder which is actually CREATE temp table and INSERT INTO statements.

Below is my code

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.Append(@"
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Student') IS NOT NULL   
    DROP TABLE #Student   

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL   
    DROP TABLE #Temp     

CREATE TABLE #Student (StudentId int,StudentName varchar(500),Marks int, DepartmentId int);");

foreach (var item in studentData)
{
    sql.AppendLine();
    sql.AppendLine("INSERT INTO #Student (");
    StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder("VALUES (");
    bool isFirstColumn = true;

    Type type = item.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = type.GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in propertyInfo)
    {
        string columnName = property.Name;
        object columnValue = property.GetValue(item);

        if (isFirstColumn)
            isFirstColumn = false;
        else
        {
           sql.Append(", ");
           values.Append(", ");
        }

         sql.Append(columnName);
         values.Append(columnValue);
    }
    sql.Append(") ");
    sql.AppendLine();
    sql.Append(values.ToString());
    sql.Append(")");
}

sql.AppendLine();
sql.Append(@"SELECT *
             INTO #Temp
             FROM
             (
                 SELECT *
                 FROM #Student s
                 JOIN Department d  ON s.DepartmentId = d.DepartmentId

             ) as t");
```

I dont have the option of using Stored Proc. Is there any better option to create Temp table than using StringBuilder which will be then inserted in SQL query?

Can we convert the data in the List into XML and then add the data in XML format in the string SQL query?

Any help or suggestions for a better code than this?

Thanks

Comment: It's obligatory to point out that this is a SQL injection risk. (My name is `") DROP TABLE department`.) Aside from that, where is the anonymous type? What is `studentData`? It seems like you have to know much more about the type. Otherwise how would you know that you need its properties in the temp table? If you know the type then you shouldn't need reflection to get its properties.

Comment: Ya I know I don't have the option of creating SQL Procedure and studentData is a list of an anonymous type having the same fields which are in #Student table. And it is an internal windows based application so I am not that worrying of SQL injection risk.

Comment: Whether it's anonymous or not, if you know the properties then you can use them explicitly. You don't have to use reflection. When use reflection like this it makes it look like you don't know what the properties are, even though you do. It also means the next developer can't easily see what the properties are. They have to go back to where the anonymous type was created and try to figure out what those properties are. We don't need reflection to "discover" what we already know.

Comment: But Scott my question is not about reflection but what will be best way to create a Temp table in this case.

Comment: Are you using ADO.NET to execute this SQL?

Comment: Yes first I am creating my query using StringBuilder and then executing using SQLAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ADO.NET, you can use [Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) and pass the Table-Valued Type to a parameterized SQL statement. I'd opt for using a stored procedure, but both will work.

**modified example usage from MS Docs (not tested)**

```
using (connection)  
{  
  // Create a DataTable with the modified rows.  
  DataTable addedStudents = StudentsDataTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);  

  // Define the INSERT-SELECT statement.  
  string sqlInsert =  
      "INSERT INTO dbo.Students (xxx, yyy)"  
      + " SELECT s.xxx, s.yyy"  
      + " FROM @tvpStudents AS s;"  

  // Configure the command and parameter.  
  SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlInsert, connection);  
  SqlParameter tvpParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpStudents", addedStudents);  
  tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;  
  tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.StudentTableType";  

  // Execute the command.  
  insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}
```